# CSS: Chrome width issue

Tags: css, google-chrome

Pls help with css & chrome, on old version of chrome last menu item is rendered on new line, but on firefox && new version of chrome all working nice.

Screen(remote debugging): 
[image: remote debug]
Desktop chrome: 
[image]
Elements:
[image]

CSS code:

```
/* menu start */
.menu, .menu * {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div#mainmenu-wrapper {
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 1100px;
}
ul#mainmenu{
    width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#mainmenu:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-left:1100px;
}
#mainmenu li {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 9px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #ffffff;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(offX=0, offY=0, color=#ffffff);
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0 7px;
    height: 38px!important;
}
#mainmenu li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#mainmenu a {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px 0;
    border-radius: 9px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px #262626 inset;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 5px 18px 7px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline;
}
#mainmenu a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
li.selected a{
    color: #f00;
}
/* menu end */
```

Comment: That's a question of padding variations across browsers. If I was you I would use percentage widths for each of the `li`s, otherwise you're going to have to hack it to be pixel perfect (then it's not responsive either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG O_O . I found the problem, missing "PT Sans" font on device.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, image, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: top; }
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block;}
body {line-height: 1;}
ol, ul { list-style: none;}
blockquote, q { quotes: none;}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {content: ''; content: none;}
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
b {font-weight:bold;}
a {text-decoration:none; border:none;}
```

use this crack css before your css.